# Why has the number of claims risen over the past few decades (doubled between 1975 and 2005)?

Tags: claims, history

I saw on https://patentlyo.com/patent/2007/12/rising-claim-co.html:

> [image]

Why has the number of claims risen over the past few decades?

---

Data:

> The chart shows the average number of total claims and independent claims for each year of issuance. The sample is drawn from 28,000 randomly selected patents that issued from 1977 and 2005. (For those who want data, the following table shows the average claim numbers by filing date.)

| Year | Avg Total Claims | Avg Ind Claims | n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1975 | 10.6 | 2.2 | 358 |
| 1976 | 10.1 | 2.0 | 616 |
| 1977 | 10.2 | 2.1 | 620 |
| 1978 | 10.7 | 2.0 | 615 |
| 1979 | 11.7 | 2.1 | 619 |
| 1980 | 11.3 | 2.0 | 608 |
| 1981 | 12.4 | 2.2 | 585 |
| 1982 | 11.6 | 2.1 | 593 |
| 1983 | 11.7 | 2.2 | 593 |
| 1984 | 11.4 | 2.1 | 614 |
| 1985 | 11.0 | 2.1 | 674 |
| 1986 | 11.8 | 2.3 | 689 |
| 1987 | 11.9 | 2.2 | 718 |
| 1988 | 12.6 | 2.3 | 824 |
| 1989 | 13.2 | 2.3 | 912 |
| 1990 | 12.9 | 2.5 | 912 |
| 1991 | 12.5 | 2.4 | 918 |
| 1992 | 13.0 | 2.5 | 932 |
| 1993 | 14.8 | 2.7 | 1005 |
| 1994 | 14.6 | 2.7 | 1173 |
| 1995 | 16.1 | 2.9 | 1344 |
| 1996 | 17.2 | 3.0 | 1329 |
| 1997 | 17.1 | 2.9 | 1645 |
| 1998 | 16.7 | 2.9 | 1562 |
| 1999 | 17.9 | 3.0 | 1666 |
| 2000 | 18.4 | 3.0 | 1717 |
| 2001 | 18.9 | 3.1 | 1615 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know, but I speculate that every time in a notable case a judge misconstrues a claim, practitioners are more motivated to include claims that use alternative wording to try to define the same invention.

Note that these averages are not from normal distributions. From PatentlyO in 2014 see this chart - [image]

By far the most popular number of claims is the 20 you get for no extra fees.  Note these are applications not issued patents. Some of the popular 20 will get canceled in prosecution.